# Runtime '3011' Error in Database

Tags: excel, runtime

I have a database which is being overhauled.
There we have a function when I click on a button it generates data from a table into an  excel sheet.
This is functioning as it should.
Database and excel file are in the same file.

Now I am trying to use this function in the new database as well.
I copied the buttons and also the event procedures accordingly but am receiving the error message: Runtime Error '3011'

here the script which works in the one database but doesn't want to work in the new one.

Script:

```
Private Sub Command95_Click()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet1", CurrentProject.Path & "\PR1.xls", False, A3
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Performance_report_HW_H1story", CurrentProject.Path & "\Performance report HW.xls", False, A3

'Change format in Excel cells
'Dim exApp As Excel.Application
'    Dim exBook As Excel.Workbook
'    Dim exSheet As Excel.Worksheet
'    Dim BookName As String

'Set exApp = New Excel.Application
'BookName = CurrentProject.Path & "\Performance report HW.xls"

'Set exBook = exApp.Workbooks.Open(BookName)

'Set exSheet = exBook.Worksheets(1)

'exSheet.Activate

'exSheet.Range("A3", "AQ30000").Font.Size = 8
'exSheet.Range("A3", "AQ30000").Font.Name = "Arial"
'exSheet.Range("l3", "l30000").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
'exSheet.Range("o3", "o30000").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

'Set exSheet1 = exBook.Worksheets(2)

'exSheet.Activate

'exSheet1.Range("A3", "AQ30000").Font.Size = 8
'exSheet.Range("A3", "AQ30000").Font.Name = "Arial"
'exSheet.Range("l3", "l30000").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
'exSheet.Range("o3", "o30000").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"


'exBook.Save

'exApp.Interactive = True
'    exBook.Close
'    Set exSheet = Nothing
'    Set exBook = Nothing
'    Set exApp = Nothing

MsgBox "File stored in " & CurrentProject.Path & "\Performance report HW.xls", vbDefaultButton1
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Am I missing something?
Why is it not working, it's the same script and also same procedure.

Comment: Sounds like Access cant see something, check that the path ways of BookName are correct.

Comment: everything there and correct....